# Can't setup KtlLogger in the clusterconfig.json of Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am having troubles setting up the KtlLogger in Servcie Fabric on a self-hosted system.

The KtlLogger preallocates 8GB of disk space by default. We are deploying this on some test machines with limited disk space. I tried to alter the json to have something like this:

```
"fabricSettings" : [{
                "name" : "Setup",
                "parameters" : [{
                        "name" : "FabricDataRoot",
                        "value" : "C:\\Service Fabric\\Data"
                    }, {
                        "name" : "FabricLogRoot",
                        "value" : "C:\\Service Fabric\\Log"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "name" : "KtlLogger",
                "parameters": [{
                        "name" : "SharedLogSizeInMB",
                        "value" : "3072"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

This produces an error:

```
Create Cluster failed with exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Fabric.WRPComm
on.ValidationException
at System.Fabric.WRPServiceCommon.Common.SettingsValidator.ValidateFabricSettings()
at System.Fabric.WRPServiceCommon.Common.DeployAnywhereSettingsValidator.Validate(Boolean isNewResource)
at System.Fabric.JsonImpl.ManifestConverter.ConvertFromJsonToXml(String jsonClusterConfigPath)
at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ClusterCmdletBase.NewCluster(String clusterConfigurationFilePath, String fabric
PackageSourcePath, Boolean rollbackOnFailure)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Fabric.WRPCommon.ValidationException
at System.Fabric.WRPServiceCommon.Common.SettingsValidator.ValidateFabricSettings()
at System.Fabric.WRPServiceCommon.Common.DeployAnywhereSettingsValidator.Validate(Boolean isNewResource)
at System.Fabric.JsonImpl.ManifestConverter.ConvertFromJsonToXml(String jsonClusterConfigPath)
at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsyncInternal>d__a.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Fabric.DeploymentManager.<CreateClusterAsync>d__0.MoveNext()<---
```

Anyone know how I can override the default SharedLogSizeInMB?

Comment: Have tried to configure manifest file as described [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-configuration.md). Doesn't work either.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was going on too. Wonder if it is a bug and I should add a ticket.

Comment: there is one more thing that you can try — create a ReliableStateManager, pass there ReliableStateManagerConfiguration with ReliableStateManagerReplicatorSettings in constructor. Maybe this approach will work.